# Video editing on Microsoft Office Communicator

Tags: video, office-communicator, ocs

Is there a way to programatically edit and compose the video streams in Office Communicator? For example, how can I merge the webcam video streams of all the participants in a single video stream with a collage of all of them? Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Communicator functions can then be called using the SDK. The SDK also seems to be very limited on what information can be obtained from the Communicator client.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=f1d1a947-6eff-4ac4-8878-f0a77894ac99&displaylang=en

you can use a OC-Plus (by Tangram)
you need a 3rd-party toolkit, which called "OC-Plus (by Tangram)". With that, you can put anything into OC Tab. And the most interesting thing is that it can help you create the Tabs on the left side of the buddylist area, like the tab style of MSN and more.

NOW the toolkit "UC Plus" and relevant services are mainly sold in China, I'm not sure if they provide material or website in English.

But you can still contact them by email ucplus@gmail.com , surely that will help find your answer.

There is a guy however that you can contact by email sunhuizlz@hotmail.com, and he says 'I can send you "ucplus" for development OC plugins' so definitely give that a go.

Hope that helps

**PK**